# Using Kingfisher, images are not loading correctly in UITableView

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, scroll, cell

I just started using KingFisher.

When you scroll too fast down a UITableView, all network/doadload request get backed up, so by time it stops scrolling, it's still finishing those previous request.

This leads to all the images flickering around with different pictures until all backed up requests are complete.

Here is my code to retrieve images from cache or network.

```
if ImageCache.defaultCache.cachedImageExistsforURL(finished_URL!) == true {
            print("image is already cached.")
            
            if cell.tag == indexPath.row{
                cell.card_imageIV.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "ic_error")
                KingfisherManager.sharedManager.retrieveImageWithURL(finished_URL!, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
                    cell.card_imageIV.image = image
                    print("Retrieved cached image")
                })
            }
            
        }else{
            cell.card_imageIV.kf_setImageWithURL(finished_URL!, placeholderImage: self.placeholderImage, optionsInfo: nil, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                print("\(card_name): Finished")
            })
        }
```

I've tried following documentation on https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher for cancelling all previous download tasks, using but didn't help.

Following code I tried:

```
// The image retrieving will stop.
imageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
```

This only cancels the current cells, at least from I can make sense of.

Answer (score 10):

I have absolutely same issue with my project. I am looking for a way to implement just the same thing as you want: if I scroll VERY fast, – I want to cancel previous downloads. Here is my approach for this, using KingFisher library(Swift 3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentify) 
    cell?.imageView?.kf.cancelDownloadTask()

}
```

This method must be declared in table view delegate. It will cancel download task task of already scrolled cell.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I also had similar race condition and by canceling on didEndDisplaying I solved the issue. Also on Android popular library Glide uses similar canceling approach, the only disadvantage is if it's almost fully downloaded it will not be cached. Did you found better solution?

Comment: Nope, I see no way to cache half-downloaded(or 95%-downloaded, if that's the way you want to put it) image. I'm not sure that kingfisher/any other caching lib support such thing.

Comment: Well not a big deal, I use your solution and it works pretty good. Thanks a lot!